# Vue 3: Component library with component that is composed of another does not render the base component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I logged an issue but, it also seems likely it's just something I'm doing wrong ..

I have a component (`CoolComponent` or `<cool-component>`) that I have defined inside a library and that is derived from another component (`BaseComponent` or `<base-component>`).

`CoolComponent.vue` looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="cool-component">
    <BaseComponent message="This is the message">
      <template v-slot:something>
        This is something!!
      </template>
    </BaseComponent>
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem is that when I use a `<cool-component>` component in a project, only the items inside the `CoolComponent` class are rendered. The `BaseComponent` component is rendered as a literal tag (`<basecomponent>` - no hyphen). I am assuming that because it's translating to `<basecomponent>` that Vue doesn't know how to render the base component.

The console contains the following warning: `[Vue warn]: resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup()`.

Not really sure what I've done wrong with setup or whether this is a bug.

Reproduction (repo) here: https://github.com/lukef/vue-component-repro.

Comment: what about `<base-component message="This is the message">`

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: could you reproduce that in codesandbox

Comment: I wasn't able to build your repo. Could you try cloning it yourself and confirm that following the instructions in the `README.md` really does work for you?

Comment: Sorry. You need a yarn install first and there was one minor issue. I amended the instructions and code but the outcome is the same. Try now.

Comment: Are you still having issues with this? I've been helping look into a similar thing for a project and found the problem to be in how the package is installed locally. If you are still looking for answers, I'd like to ask you a few things about your local implementation and maybe the same thing we found will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time, but I think I have solved the riddle now. See at the bottom for the `tl;dr`, here follows the "making of" first.

The first observation was that copying the components in `comp` unmodified to `comp-test` resulted in a working page. Then I tried to import them directly from `comp` using relative paths which resulted in the original failure. This led me to conclude that there must be some difference in the surroundings. After some experiments, I found that the `node_modules` in `comp` caused the disruption: after removing these, the inclusion from `comp` worked as well. Looking into the files in `comp-test/node_modules/comp`, I found that the original `node_modules` from `comp` are copied over as well. Now I had to find a way to add `comp` to `comp-test` without copying the `node_modules`. Even though `node_modules` are not published, neither `.gitignore` nor `.npmignore` had any effect. The solution was to create a tarball using `yarn pack` and import it from `comp-test`.

Probably the original problem is some conflict in the two `node_modules`, but it only occurs when there is a `<slot>` in `BaseComponent` - strange...

This results in the following fixes:

in `comp/package.json:11`

```
"build": "yarn build:lib && yarn pack",
```

(instead of just `yarn build:lib`), and in `comp/package.json:15`

```
"comp": "file:../comp/comp-v0.1.0.tgz"
```

(instead of `"comp": "../comp"`). In order to refresh `comp` after some modifications, you have to run the following commands:

in `comp`:

```
$ yarn build
```

then in `comp-test`:

```
$ yarn add file:../comp/comp-v0.1.0.tgz
$ yarn serve
```

Note that the actual result of `yarn pack` is not quite what you might think reading its description - at least for me "package dependencies" mean ultimately some content of some `node_modules` directory. Instead it creates a tarball that contains more or less the same files as what is published using `yarn publish`. After `yarn build:lib && yarn pack`, the content of the tarball is refreshed, and `yarn add file:../comp/comp-v0.1.0.tgz` forces a refresh of `comp-test/node_modules/comp`.